# How can I get this false value in Cloud Function ? And also how can I change the pushId

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/isAllowed/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you use in your question is the one of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions corresponding to versions before version 1.0.0. You should use the latest versions, and use a different syntax, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Then for versions >= 1.0 you would do as follows:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database
  .ref('/isAllowed/{pushId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // const beforeData = change.before.val();  data before the write
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
    console.log(afterData);  // -> you get false
    return change.after.ref.set(true);  // -> you update to e.g. true
  });
```

As explained in the doc mentioned above

> For onWrite and onUpdate events, the data parameter has before and
>   after fields. Each of these is a DataSnapshot with the same methods
>   available in [`admin.database.DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot).

So, in the code above, we use the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#ref) property of this DataSnapshot to update it with the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#set) method (we could also use `update()`).